# how to display records based on one column from table in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

it displays error : table does not have primary key

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet("ds1");

DataTable dt = ds.Tables.Add("tblcategory");

string s = textBox1.Text.ToString();




DataRow foundRow = ds.Tables["tblcategory"].Rows.Find(s);

if (foundRow != null)
{
    MessageBox.Show(foundRow[0].ToString());
}
```

Comment: on which column you want so search

Comment: Have a look at LINQ2SQL

Answer (score 1):

You have to set table structure and, in particular, primary key column(s), to be able to find rows with [`Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydd48eyk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), e.g.:

```
var column = dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
column.AllowDBNull = false;
column.Unique = true;
```